# Slide alternado usando Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho 3 links com 3 conteúdos associados aos mesmos, quando clico em um dos links a `div` com o conteúdo correspondente é exibida.

Caso uma outra `div` que não seja correspondente ja esteja sendo exibida ela é fechada e a correta é aberta, porém o `slideToggle` do `jquery`não esta fazendo um efeito uniforme, se uma `div` "x" estiver aberta e eu clicar para abrir a "y", ao invés de o slide seguir sempre do topo para baixo ela alterna fazendo o slide de baixo para cima.

E se eu clicar 2x no mesmo link a `div` abre e fecha rapidamente mesmo tendo o `toggle` definido.

```js
$('a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var content = $(this).data('section');
  var contents = $('.container .section');
  
  $contents.each(function(index, el) {
    if ($(el).is(':visible') && $(el).data('content') !== content) {
      $(el).slideToggle('slow');
    }
  });
  
  $('[data-content="'+content+'"]').slideToggle('slow');
})
```

```css
.container .section {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="" data-section="1">Section 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-section="2">Section 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-section="3">Section 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section" data-content="1">
    Section 1
  </div>
  <div class="section" data-content="2">
    Section 2
  </div>
  <div class="section" data-content="3">
    Section 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Se preferir veja também no [code pen](http://codepen.io/rafa-acioly/pen/qRQxVr)

Comment: Primeiro, está dando erro no seu código. Ao definir a variável `contents`, você esqueceu de defini-la com o nome correto `$contents`. Segundo, se eu entendi direito, você quer que no _toggle_ a `div` apareça sempre por um caminho, de cima para baixo, é isso? Se não for, explique melhor o que você precisa.